# Removing elements from a list in python based on digits

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list of integers and I want to remove all integers that have 7, 8, 9 or 0 in them.

This is what I have done so far:

```
import numpy as np
def P(n):
    list = []
    for i in range(10**(n-1),7*10**(n-1)):
        list.append(i)
    for i in list:
        for k in str(i):
            if k in ['7','8','9','0']: list.remove(i)
            #elif k == '8': list.remove(i)
            #elif k == '9': list.remove(i)
            #elif k == '10': list.remove(i)
    return list
```

But it returns this:

```
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 58, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 68]
```

How can i fix this code so that it gets rid of the unwanted values? i.e. 18, 20, 28, 30 etc.

Comment: Do modify a list that you are iterating over - craziness ensues. Also don't name a variable `list` it hides pythons builtin type. `return [i for i in range(10**(n-1),7*10**(n-1)) if all(c not in '7890' for c in str(i))]`

Answer (score 3):

You can recreate the list using list comprehension and built-in `any()` method to check if any of the digits is in the unwanted list. In order to iterate through the numbers you need to type cast them to `str()` first. For example:

```
def P(n):
    l = []
    for i in range(10**(n-1),7*10**(n-1)):
        l.append(i)
    l = [x for x in l if not any(y in ['7', '8', '9', '0'] for y in str(x))]
```

Output:

```
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66]
```

You can also avoid creating the initial list and the for loop by using:

```
def P(n):
    l = range(10**(n-1),7*10**(n-1))
    l = [x for x in l if not any(y in ['7', '8', '9', '0'] for y in str(x))]
```

Answer (score 1):

another filter test option is to use `set` intersection

```
n=2
print([i for i in range(10**(n-1),7*10**(n-1))
         if not {'7','8','9','0'} & set(str(i))
       ])
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66]
```

and while the warnings against modifying a list when iterating over it in a Python `for` are on target

you can literally modify a list while 'iterating' in the general sense if you keep track of how you modify the index, how you test for completion

```
n =2
lst = list(range(10**(n-1),7*10**(n-1)))
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
    if {'7','8','9','0'} & set(str(lst[i])):
        lst.pop(i)
    else:
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the code before iterating list to list = range (10**n-1,7*10**n-1)
range returns a list there is no need to iterate over the list just to copy it.
Second, in the second loop k iterate over the characters of every string in list.
for i in list:
 for k in ['7','8','9','0',]:
   if k in i:
    list.remove(i)